# How to concatenate secrets into workflow action on GitHub?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-secret

I would like to concatenate multiple secrets into my workflow action on GitHub.

The example that comes to mind would be to create a full path from folder to filename.

Answer (score 45):

To concatenate secrets into a workflow action on GitHub:

`${{ format('{0}/{1}.{2}', secrets.FOLDER, secrets.FILENAME, secrets.EXT) }}`

Sources:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#format